# How to get all the paths I want using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

**I have a tree of objects and I want to get the ids of all nodes whose check property is true and store them in an array,I used recursion, but no valid result, my data object is as follows

```
    "id": "1000",
    "parentId": "-1",
    "check": true,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "2000",
            "parentId": "1000",
            "check": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "3000",
                    "parentId": "2000",
                    "check": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "3001",
                    "parentId": "2000",
                    "check": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "3002",
                    "parentId": "2000",
                    "check": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1001",
    "parentId": "-1",
    "check": true,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "2001",
            "parentId": "1001",
            "check": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "3003",
                    "parentId": "2001",
                    "check": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "3004",
                    "parentId": "2001",
                    "check": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "3005",
                    "parentId": "2001",
                    "check": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

However, now I got an answer like this,Here's what I tried, but it's not what I ended up wanting

```
function getCheck(arr) {
    let result = []
    arr.forEach(item => {
        if (item.check) {
            result.push(item.id)
        }
        if (item.children) {
            let child = getCheck(item.children)
            if (child.length) {
                result.push(child)
            }
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

[image]

What I want to get is

[image]

Is it possible to convert the above answer，Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: I have [this possible approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6vqEw) but it generates an element for each node with `check` being true, even the internal nodes.  But your (hard to read picture of) desired output seems to only include leaf nodes. Do you only want *leaf* nodes where `check` is true for itself *and all its ancestor nodes*?  Or what?  Like, if `"1001"` has `check` as `false`, what do you want to see?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand,  that the picture is the result of code execution. If the root node is empty, it is an empty array

Comment: I asked "if `"1001"` has `check` as `false`, what do you want to see?" Did you answer that?  That's not the same as the root node being empty.

Comment: then only the root node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use another variable (that defaults to `[]`) to store the path or depth we are currently at. Then, if the item has children, we get all the checks there and add them to the result, otherwise, that means we're at a leaf and we add the item's ID directly.

```js
const data = [{"id":"1000","parentId":"-1","check":!0,"children":[{"id":"2000","parentId":"1000","check":!0,"children":[{"id":"3000","parentId":"2000","check":!0},{"id":"3001","parentId":"2000","check":!0},{"id":"3002","parentId":"2000","check":!1}]}]},{"id":"1001","parentId":"-1","check":!0,"children":[{"id":"2001","parentId":"1001","check":!0,"children":[{"id":"3003","parentId":"2001","check":!0},{"id":"3004","parentId":"2001","check":!0},{"id":"3005","parentId":"2001","check":!0}]}]}];

function getCheck(arr, path = []) {
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach(item => {
        if (item.children) { // has children, not a leaf
            // add all its children
            result.push(...getCheck(item.children, [...path, item.id]));
        } else { // no children, is leaf
            result.push([...path, item.id]); // add its ID
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(getCheck(data));
```